# Check if any values have changed a certain amount

Tags: objective-c, math

Does anyone know any efficient ways to check if any set of integers contains an integer that has changed by a certain amount.

For example I have:

```
int1 = 10;
int2 = 20;
int3 = 30;
```

And I want to know if any of these 3 integers change by `30`

Now if `int1` becomes `40` than the call should be triggered. At first I thought of just doing something like this.

```
if (abs((int1+int2+int3)-(newInt1+newInt2+newInt3)) >= 30) {
```

But many problems can arise from this...

- False triggers (e.g. each new int value increases by 10, making the NET change greater than 30 but not necessarily any individual int greater than 30)
- Untriggered reactions (e.g. one of the new integer values has increased by 50 so it should be called but then another new integer value is decreased by 50 (again, it should be called) but the net change is now zero because `-50+50=0`)

Does anyone have any efficient way of doing this? *(Yes, I know obviously I could just check each value individually with OR statements...)*

So far this is my best stab at it

```
if ((((abs(int1-newInt1))>=30)+((abs(int2-newInt2))>=30)+((abs(int3-newInt3))>=30))>0) {
```

But that's *basically* the same as using an OR statement (probably even takes a little longer than an OR statment.

Comment: so, why cant you just check using an or?

Comment: There cannot be a way better than the one you are using

Comment: @ElKamina is there a way to shorten it using `expression-notation`?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw You can probably do 'or' instead of '+'. Then it will stop executing the rest of the conditions if one of the conditions is found to be true

Comment: @ElKamina True! I could also probably check the regular >=30 and then check the "absolute" value (or better yet, just check if it's <=-30) that way it will stop if it can before running the absolute function which could take longer on a micro-scale.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can get any faster than that, and unless you're dealing with hundreds of millions of integers, this should not introduce a significant performance penalty.

---

However, you might want to be "clever". What if you somehow "checksum" the two sums? For example, multiply all the old and new numbers with the nth prime, then check if the difference of the new and old sum divided by the `index`th prime is the amount you want.

```
int sum(int arr[], size_t n)
{
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        n += primes[i] * arr[i];

    return n;
}

int primes[3] = { 2, 3, 5 }; // or more
int olds[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
int news[3] = { 40, 20, 30 };

int nth = 0; // check first
int change_expected = 30;
int oldsum = sum(olds, 3);
int newsum = sum(news, 3);
if ((newsum - oldsum) / primes[nth] == change_expected) {
    // 1st value changed as expected
}
```

Note that this will take way more time and CPU cycles that your naive approach.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Why are you using primes? Also what is the first half of your code doing? the "return n" stuff?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Using primes is done in order to avoid false positives (if you multiply by primes, there's no way two differences in the result can coalesce/be the same after division). The `sum` function does what its name suggests: it sums the elements of its first array argument, each multiplied by its corresponding prime factor in the list of primes.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! But where are you multiplying by primes? Is that in the first half of the code? When you take the sum you are multiplying by a prime for each value (e.g. newsum[0] = [news[0]*primes[0])?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes, it is.

Comment: Ahhh!! That is so cool! Of course this is a slower method (when checking 3 integer values) but I am so glad to learn a use for `primes`!

Comment: +1 Thankyou very much for teaching me that neat trick! Does it have a name?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I'm sure it does, but I don't know it, I've just come up with this.

Comment: Very cool! So we would also put an absolute value in your last conditional-statement? That would work still with this prime method right? Or does this only work for positive differences?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I believe this is supposed to work regardless of the sign of the numbers, but beware and don't use the `abs()` function if you're dealing with integers. Instead check for equality with `change_expected` or `-change_expected`, or pay attention to the sign of the change.

Comment: Wait, why shouldn't I use `abs` with integers?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw 1. Conceptually, it's bad (why use floating-point numbers for solving problems related to integers?) 2. floating-point operations are not precise. For large integers, for example, only even integers can be represented using the most popular floating-point representation.

Comment: So how should I get the absolute value of an integer? Take the square-root of that integer squared?

Comment: Convert it to a string and strip "-" then convert it back to an int?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No, `sqrt()` involves floating-point trickery too. Just use the definition (but really, it's out of scope here, google it). And no, using strings for math problems is even worse.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes, that's definitely better. Or `x < 0 ? -x : x`.

Comment: Now that's a notation I've never seen!!! What's it called? :) Where do you learn stuff like this?! Haha!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw 1. Conditional expression. From any beginner C tutorial.

Comment: This answer was helpful but I don't think it is the _best_ answer per-say, it's just a *neat* answer :) I upvoted this for the record. But after trying it some more today I am getting weird values... like if I only use the number 1 and 3 in OldSum and I use the number 2 and 5 in NewSum... perhaps the numbers in OldSum and NewSum can't be smaller than their respective prime? Anyways, I still haven't changed my upvote since this works if I use a floor function on it after dividing by the respective prime. (Get's rid of my weird results)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *objective*-c, you can always create an object that does exactly what you want (see class below the example).  The main benefit of doing it this way is that you don't have to check every integer every time one is set.  You simply check each number *as it is changed* to see if it has changed too much.

**Usage Example:**

```
// myNumbers.confined will be true until you create a number, and THEN change it by 30 or more.
ARConfinedNumbers *myNumbers = [ARConfinedNumbers new];
[myNumbers addNumber:10];
[myNumbers addNumber:20];
[myNumbers addNumber:30];

[myNumbers replaceNumberAtIndex:0 withObject:40];

// No longer confined because we have changed 10 to 40
if (!myNumbers.confined)
    NSLog(@"Not confined.");

// Reset
[myNumbers setConfined:YES];
```

Here is the class that I wrote to do this.  Note that I used an `NSArray`, assuming that you were programming for iOS/MacOS but you can replace the NSArray with something else if you aren't using those classes.  This should give you a great starting point though.

**ARConfinedNumbers.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ARConfinedNumbers : NSObject

// confined is true if the numbers have not been changed by more than 30.
// This can be reset by setting it to YES.
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL confined;

// Methods to manipulate the set of numbers
// Add more array-type-methods as needed
- (void)addNumber:(int)number;
- (void)replaceNumberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(int)number;
- (int)numberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSUInteger)count;

@end
```

**ARConfinedNumbers.m**

```
#import "ARConfinedNumbers.h"

/* Private Methods */
@interface ARConfinedNumbers()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *numbers;

@end

@implementation ARConfinedNumbers

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _confined = YES;
        _numbers = [NSMutableArray new];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addNumber:(int)number
{
    [self.numbers addObject:@(number)];
}

- (void)replaceNumberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(int)number
{
    if (index < self.numbers.count)
    {
        if (number)
        {
            int existingNumber = [self.numbers[index] intValue];
            if (abs(existingNumber - number) >= 30)
                self.confined = NO;

            [self.numbers replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@(number)];
        }
    }
}

- (int)numberAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index < self.numbers.count)
        return [self.numbers[index] intValue];

    return 0;
}

- (NSUInteger)count
{
    return self.numbers.count;
}

@end
```